# Не работают медиазапросы. Отображаются оба варианта одновременно

Tags: css3, media-queries

Пытаюсь отдавать разный контент на разных устройствах.

1) Для мобильных устройств делаю кликабельным номер телефона.

2) Для десктопов убираю кликабельность.

И что-то не работают у меня медиазапросы. **Отображаются оба варианта одновременно.**

Не могу найти ошибки, хоть убей. Медиазапросы меняла местами, думала, что проблема в порядке следования. Не помогло :(

Подскажите,пожалуйста, где я ошиблась.

Код такой:

```css
@media screen (max-width : 800px)
{ .show-on-mobile { display: inline; }
  .hide-on-mobile { display: none; }
}
 
@media screen (min-width: 801px)   
{   .show-on-mobile { display: none; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: inline; }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

 <p style="text-align: center;" id="contacts" itemprop="telephone"> 
 <span class="show-on-mobile">
<a href="tel:+ номер телефона"> номер телефона</a>
</span> 
        
<span class="hide-on-mobile"> номер телефона
</span> 
        
</p>
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тебе

```css
@media (max-width : 800px)
{ 
    .show-on-mobile { display: inline; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: none; }
}
 
@media (min-width: 801px)   
{   
    .show-on-mobile { display: none; }
    .hide-on-mobile { display: inline; }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

 <p style="text-align: center;" id="contacts" itemprop="telephone"> 
 <span class="show-on-mobile">
<a href="tel:+ номер телефона"> номер телефона</a>
</span> 
        
<span class="hide-on-mobile"> номер телефона
</span> 
        
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А в чем разница между media и media screen? Это мне для вящего понимания и осознания :)

Comment: `screen` - тип устройства - экран. `@media` - обобщённый медиазапрос, независимый от типа устройства